# How to change img source with cordova/phonegap on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I'm developing with cordova/phonegap a little app.

I want an image to move on screen to fixed positions. For that I placed 2 img tags in HTML, and via javascript I change "src" of the img tags, making one have the img and setting the other to blank.

This happens when user clics on screen button.

While testing it on browser and on Android devices it all worked fine, but, on iOS, the image doesn't dissapear, so I'm stuck with the screen filled with the same image all over.

How can I make it dissapear??

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Container" class="ui-grid-b">
  <div class="ui-block-a"><img src="" id="izq" style="margin-top: -23%; max-width:40%; max-height:40%;" /></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><strong><span id="mid">Tap the button</span></strong></div>
  <div class="ui-block-c"><img src="" id="der" style="margin-top: -23%; max-width:40%; max-height:40%;" /></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
  var delay = 500;
  if (chosen == "izq"){
    timeEstrella = setTimeout(function(){
        izq.src = "estrella.png";
        der.src = "";
      },delay); 
  }
  else {
    timeEstrella = setTimeout(function(){
        izq.src = "";
        der.src = "estrella.png";
      },delay); 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you just hide the image using CSS. You can set the style property on the image:

```
izq.style.display = 'none';
der.style.display = 'block;
```

Or use classes and a stylesheet:

```
/* in your stylesheet */
.hidden { display: none; }


/* In your JavaScript */
izq.className = 'hidden';
der.className = '';
```

Comment: Ok, you gave me the idea. At the end I didn't use display, but used `izq.style.visibility = 'visible';` and `der.style.visibility = 'hidden';`. Thanks

Comment: @Sascuash Note that visibility will still retain space in the DOM, display will not.

Comment: Thanks @Jivings, didn't knew that